# How to apply Spring AOP in individual methods

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-aop

Actually i am working in a Spring MVC project and i successfully applied and  configured Spring AOP in my project but i want to apply Spring AOP on individual methods like which method i want to check its working or not.

**Its my Aspect code:**

```
   @Pointcut("execution(* com.xyz.dao..*.*(..))")
    public void generalPointCut() {

   }
   @Before("generalPointCut()")
   public void logBefore(JoinPoint joinpoint) {
    Object clazz = joinpoint.getTarget().getClass().getName();
    String methodName = joinpoint.getSignature().getName();
    log.info("Entring in Method" + methodName + " in Calss " + clazz);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

*(followup after comment)*

You can be as precise as you want in the Pointcut execution expression. For instance if you wanted to be super specific in terms of the method name including return type and args signature it would look like this:

```
@Pointcut("execution(public String com.xyz.dao.findMyEntity(Long))")
```

---

[Take a look at the execution pointcut expression examples in the Spring Documetation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#aop-pointcuts-examples).

What you have already is intercepting all methods/classes within the `com.xyz.dao` package and subpackages, by using `*` as a wildcard.

As you'll see in the examples you can drill down to the method name level.

Comment: I know its working for com.xyz.dao. package and subpackages but if i dont want to take some method in this package then what should i do

Comment: amended answer to add an example

Comment: if you find this answer useful you can upvote/accept it